# How to place an arrow on top and to the right of a matrix

Tags: matrices, arrows

I am trying to create a matrix shown below

[image]

but I want the *left arrow* to be on the *right side of the matrix*

because I want to have the name of the matrix on the left side.

Here is what I have:

```
\[
M =\begin{bmatrix} 
f(1,1) & f(1,2) & \dots \\
f(2,1) & f(2,2) & \dots  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots 
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

I am not sure how to proceed after that.
Anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!! Off-topic: shouldn't it say "j changes" in the horizontal line?

Comment: You are right, it should!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've slightly modified marmot's solution in order to avoid using `tikzmark`.

I've also used `Triangle` as arrow tips and other little changes.

My solution works also if you haven't updated your distribution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary[arrows.meta]

\begin{document}
\[
M =\tikz[remember picture, baseline=(mat.center)]{\node[inner sep=0](mat){$\begin{bmatrix} 
f(1,1) & f(1,2) & \dots \\
f(2,1) & f(2,2) & \dots  \\
f(3,1) & f(3,2) & \dots  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
 & &  \\
\end{bmatrix}$};}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,
>=Triangle]
\draw[blue,thick,->] node[anchor=south west] (nn1) at (mat.north west)
{$n$ columns} (nn1.east) -- (nn1-|mat.north east) 
node[midway,above,black]{$i$ changes};
\draw[red,thick,->] node[anchor=north west,align=center, inner xsep=0pt] (nn2) at 
(mat.north east)
{$m$\\ rows} (nn2.south) -- (nn2.south|-mat.south) 
node[midway,above,black,rotate=-90]{$j$ changes};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ALB You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

With `tikzmark` it is straightforward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\[
M =\hspace*{1.5cm}\tikzmarknode{mat}{\begin{bmatrix} 
f(1,1) & f(1,2) & \dots \\
f(2,1) & f(2,2) & \dots  \\
f(3,1) & f(3,2) & \dots  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
 & &  \\
\end{bmatrix}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[blue,thick,-latex] node[anchor=south west] (nn1) at (mat.north west)
{$n$ columns} (nn1.east) -- (nn1-|mat.north east) 
node[midway,above,black]{$i$ changes};
\draw[red,thick,-latex] node[anchor=north east,align=center] (nn2) at (mat.north west)
{$m$\\ rows} (nn2.south) -- (nn2.south|-mat.south west) 
node[midway,above,black,rotate=90]{$j$ changes};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\[
M =\tikzmarknode{mat}{\begin{bmatrix} 
f(1,1) & f(1,2) & \dots \\
f(2,1) & f(2,2) & \dots  \\
f(3,1) & f(3,2) & \dots  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots \\
 & &  \\
\end{bmatrix}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[blue,thick,-latex] node[anchor=south west] (nn1) at (mat.north west)
{$n$ columns} (nn1.east) -- (nn1-|mat.north east) 
node[midway,above,black]{$i$ changes};
\draw[red,thick,-latex] node[anchor=north west,align=center] (nn2) at 
(mat.north east)
{$m$\\ rows} (nn2.south) -- (nn2.south|-mat.south) 
node[midway,above,black,rotate=90]{$j$ changes};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, is there any way to put the 'm rows, j changes' and red arrow on the right side of the matrix so it is not between the M and the matrix?

Comment: @ALB Yes. (But if you want the arrow on the right, why do you post a screen shot in which it is on the other side?)

Comment: I posted this screenshot because it was the closest that I could find to what I wanted to draw. I described what I wanted in the question but I should have made it more clear. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, this is exactly what I need, unfortunately it does not work for me. When I type the solution I get:'' !Undefined control sequence. M=\tikzmarknode''. Is there another package needed except the ones you have on the top?

Comment: @ALB You haven't updated your TeX installation in a while, right? \tikzmarknode has been added last year. And sorry for being so direct: it is not the purpose of this site to convert screen shots into LaTeX code, nor to provide a hotline for TeX issues. There are two possibilities: either my answer solves your original problem, in which case I'd kindly like to ask to accept it, or it does not, in which case I will be happy to delete it.